# Vscode not giving the option to open remote repository

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, blink, codespaces

I created some Github repositories from my computer, but my computer became old and I got an iPad.

With my iPad, I started two new Github repositories, creating a README.md file for each one. Then, I started to develop some code in those with Codespaces.

Now, I want to continue developing, but using Vscode from Blink App instead Codespaces. The problem arises when I try to open my repositories. Vscode from Blink only give me the option to open the repositories that I created with my computer, not the last two ones (created with my iPad).

I have no idea about what's happening and why Vscode from Blink does not allow me to open all repositories.

Please, may I have your help?

I tried to make the repository public, just in case... but it doesn't work either. All my repositories are private and Vscode for Blink opens only those created with my computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the repository, go to "Settings" -> "Collaborators and Teams" and there, include a member (include yourself if you are who want to access).

This member will have access to this repo from vscode (blink).